# Fish Shell causes Login Loop when is default (Fedora 26)

Tags: fedora, fish, gnome-3, oh-my-fish

I have installed a fresh Fedora 26, when I install fish (comes with 2.3.1 but I upgraded to 2.6) and I set it as default shell (`chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish`) works as expected... until I restart the PC and I try to login; gdm successfully logs me in, but after a few screen flashes it returns me to login screen, leaving me unable to login to my user.

I temporary solved this by login in another tty (Ctrl+Alt+F2) with my user and changed the shell back to bash: `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

Have someone else had this same issue? I've installed Gnome Ubuntu 17.04 and I couldn't reproduce this. Also, this is a common symptom for buggy nvidia drivers with wayland, mutter package buggy version, and incorrect home folder permissions. It was hard for me to find that fish was the actual culprit.

**Update**

After installing Fedora 27 and having the same issue, I started from scratch, and basically, to reproduce this is following these steps:

- Install [grc](https://github.com/garabik/grc)
- Install Fish
- Install [Oh-My-Fish](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish)
- Install Oh-My-Fish [grc plugin-in](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-grc)

Comment: what happens when you do `fish --login`?

Comment: Nothing particular, It just starts a fish session without asking the password.

Comment: Just remembered, I encountered this exact same thing with Ubuntu when I upgraded to kernel 4.10. I have to stick with the 4.8 kernel. Don't know why

Comment: Please consider opening this as an [issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues) in Fish's github repository, with as much (anonymized) data - particularly logs - as you can provide. Fish never claimed to be a POSIX compatible, drop-in replacement for any shell in any use-case, but I believe such breaking behavior will draw strong attention.

Comment: I would need to debug further, I just installed in a VM a fresh Fedora 26, installed fish, set as default and it worked. I guess something with my dot files doesn't work well. If I found something I'll post it here. Thanks for the responses.